# Socket.IO authentication logic seems to work, but unauthenticated socket is allowed anyway

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to set up NodeJS + Socket.IO for WebSockets.  The socket part works fine but obviously, we want security so I found some guides which show how to set up a Socket.IO middleware which is supposed to authenticate all sockets first.  This is the code I have so far:

```
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var cookie = require("cookie");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(port);
var io = socketio.listen(server);

// This is the middleware which supposed to check the session cookie
io.use(function (socket, next) {
    var handshakeData = socket.request;

    if (handshakeData.headers.cookie.indexOf('connect.sid') > -1) {
        handshakeData.cookie = cookie.parse(handshakeData.headers.cookie);
        handshakeData.sessionID = cookieParser.signedCookie(handshakeData.cookie['connect.sid'], 'foobar');

        if (!handshakeData.sessionID) {
            next(new Error('Cookie is invalid.'));
        }
    } else {
        next(new Error('No cookie found.'));
    }

    next();
});

var namespaced = io.of('/socket/test');
namespaced.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('a user connected to /socket/test');

    socket.on('fetch', function (args) {
        // The unauthenticated browser still executes this next line!
        namespaced.emit('you got some data!');
    });
});
```

The thing is, the middleware logic seems to be just fine.  I've tried it with an authenticated browser and an unauthenticated browser.  The unauthenticated browser correctly returns `next(new Error('some error'))`, which is how the docs say you're supposed to handle authentication - http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace#use(fn:function):namespace

But despite the fact that the authentication middleware returns an error, the socket is still allowed and the client receives data.

FYI, I am running Socket.IO 1.3.6 (the latest) on top of Node 0.10.24.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always call `next` at the end of your middleware. You need to do `return next(new Error(...));` when using `next` on errors, or the `next` at the end will always get executed.